# Python OS module error

Tags: python, macos, operating-system, subprocess

The following code, in Python 2.7, does not work:

```
import os

def dockSuck():
    os.system("echo Switching to suck effect.")
    os.system("defaults write com.apple.dock mineffect suck")
    os.system("killall dock")

dockSuck()
```

It prints out `Switching to suck effect.` and `No matching processes belonging to you were found`. It *should* switch the minimize effect (on a Mac) to the hidden suck effect (then reset the dock by `killall`ing it), but it returns an error instead.

Comment: Just to be sure, you can manually enter these commands and they work as expected?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dock process on osx is named Dock - note the uppercase.

```
$ ps -ef |grep dock -i
  501   359     1   0 17Oct14 ??         0:57.16 /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/MacOS/Dock
  501   423     1   0 17Oct14 ??         0:03.09 /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/XPCServices/com.apple.dock.extra.xpc/Contents/MacOS/com.apple.dock.extra
  501  2259   359   0 17Oct14 ??         0:37.98 /System/Library/CoreServices/Dock.app/Contents/Resources/DashboardClient.app/Contents/MacOS/DashboardClient
```

Modify your killall statement as `os.system("killall Dock")`

Comment: and, as a side note, you might want to send `killall -kill Dock` just to ensure all the processes are killed.

Comment: Ah, yes, it worked. I'll make it accepted in a couple minutes. =) Thanks for the help!

Comment: I know; I'm about to do it. There's still a delay for the check button for me.